# Redshift list 3 most recent values per year

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column of dates and I want to find the three maximum dates for each year I have tried the following.

```
select max(date, rank() over (partition by SPLIT_PART(date, '-', 1) order by date desc)
from table
;
```

My desired output would be

```
2013,2010-12-31
2013,2010-12-30
2013,2010-12-29
```

also there are repeats dates in the table so I would have to filter those out as well

Comment: is the column datatype `date`?

Comment: yes the datatype is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicate dates, you can `partition by` the year part of date and get the latest 3 dates per year. Use `distinct` (if needed) in the final query to remove the duplicates, if any.

```
select yr,date
from (select date_part(year,date) as yr,date
      ,dense_rank() over (partition by date_part(year,date) order by date desc) as rnk
     from table
     ) t
where rnk<=3
```